# Ajax Error : Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token '<'

Tags: javascript, php, ajax

So, I was a bug on a big old Back-End made from skratch from 2012.

I'm not an AJAX pro but manage to see this error in console :

```
VM687:1 Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token '<'
    at XMLHttpRequest.xhr_object.onreadystatechange (core.js:1050)
```

https://i.stack.imgur.com/HBRsL.jpg

So this is the core.js part it refers about :

```
function gestionFactureDetail(prd, action) {
    var a = document.getElementById(prd);
    var data = 'a=a';
    data = data + '&action=' + action;


    for (var i = 0; i < a.length; i++) {
        if (a.elements[i].tagName == 'INPUT' || a.elements[i].tagName == 'SELECT') {
            if (a.elements[i].type == 'checkbox') {
                if (a.elements[i].checked == true) {
                    data = data + "&" + a.elements[i].name + '=1';
                } else {
                    data = data + "&" + a.elements[i].name + '=';
                }
            } else {
                data = data + "&" + a.elements[i].name + '=' + a.elements[i].value;
            }
        }
        if (a.elements[i].tagName == 'TEXTAREA') {
            var b = a.elements[i].value;
            data = data + "&" + a.elements[i].name + '=' + escape(b);
        }
    }

    var xhr_object = null;
    if (window.XMLHttpRequest) // Firefox
        xhr_object = new XMLHttpRequest();
    else if (window.ActiveXObject) // Internet Explorer
        xhr_object = new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");
    else { // XMLHttpRequest non supporté par le navigateur
        alert("Votre navigateur ne supporte pas les objets XMLHTTPRequest...");
        return;
    }
    xhr_object.open("GET", 'facture_gestion_req.php?' + data, true);
    xhr_object.onreadystatechange = function () {
        if (xhr_object.readyState == 4) {
            eval(xhr_object.responseText);
        }
    }
    xhr_object.send(null);

}
```

The "1050" line the javascript console refers to is just before last line :

```
eval(xhr_object.responseText);
```

I can also give you the PHP code to what it refers :

**facturelibre_gestion_req.php**

```
<?php
include("inc/connection.php");

$action = $_GET["action"];
$contenu_factnum = $db->quote($_GET["contenu_factnum"] ? $_GET["contenu_factnum"] : 0);
$contenu_num = $db->quote($_GET["contenu_num"]);
$contenu_produit = $db->quote($_GET["contenu_produit"]);
$contenu_tva = $db->quote($_GET["contenu_tva"]);
$contenu_pu = $db->quote($_GET["contenu_pu"]);
$contenu_remise = $db->quote(trim($_GET["contenu_remise"], ' %'));
$contenu_qtite = $db->quote($_GET["contenu_qtite"]);
$contenu_montant = $db->quote($_GET["contenu_montant"]);
$eta_num = $db->quote($_GET["eta_num"]);
$eta_num_non_quote = $_GET["eta_num"];

if ($action == "creer")
{
    $add = $db->query(
        "INSERT INTO facture_contenu (
            contenu_factnum,
            contenu_texte,
            contenu_tva,
            contenu_pu,
            contenu_remise,
            contenu_qtite,
            contenu_montant
        ) VALUES (
            $contenu_factnum,
            $contenu_produit,
            $contenu_tva,
            $contenu_pu,
            $contenu_remise,
            $contenu_qtite,
            $contenu_montant
         )"
    );
}
if ($action == "maj") {
    $del =
        $db->query("
            UPDATE
                facture_contenu
            SET
                contenu_texte   = $contenu_produit,
                contenu_tva     = $contenu_tva,
                contenu_pu      = $contenu_pu,
                contenu_remise  = $contenu_remise,
                contenu_qtite   = $contenu_qtite,
                contenu_montant = $contenu_montant
            WHERE
                contenu_num     = $contenu_num
        ");
}
if ($action == "sup") {
    $del =
        $db->query("
            DELETE FROM
                facture_contenu
            WHERE
                contenu_num     = $contenu_num
        ");
}
```

If you have any idea or lead, please let me know, because I'm totally lost... :(

Comment: Please add `console.log(xhr_object.responseText);` before the line of the error and show the output of the console.

Comment: `facturelibre_gestion_req.php` returns markup (or xml) but your script expects something that can be executed (`eval(...)`)

Comment: Yes it probably is a sql error that is returned...

Comment: Or a 404, or some other error which returns html

Comment: Adding `console.log(xhr_object.responseText);` before or after the line doesn't display anything :(

Comment: Do you have checked your browsers console?

Comment: Ah ! I refresh with SHIFT and now it displays ! It comes from a wrong value in the "GET" !

I added the "get" command to a console.log you can easily get where the error is :

`a=a&action=valider&contenu_factnum=1616&contenu_produit=23&contenu_tva=0.00&int_num=2352&contenu_pu=25.00&contenu_remise=5.00 %&contenu_qtite=30&contenu_montant=712.5`

the "Remise" has a "%" character that causes error, so I'm gonna head on this direction ! Probably need to add a convertion to remove that stupid sign !

Thank you !